# Layer not repainting using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, layers, rendering

I'm trying to change the color ramp for a raster layer using PyQGIS.

What I have works, but the layer doesn't redraw. However, if I open the layer properties and click "Apply", the map redraws.

I've called both [`triggerRepaint`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.triggerRepaint) and [`iface.mapCanvas().refresh()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapCanvas.html?highlight=mapcanvas#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.refresh), both which are not producing the expected result.

**plugin**

```py
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

# do this otherwise you have to constantly declare the class you want
# to use
import qgis

class MyTool:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction("My Tool", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.setObjectName("MyToolAction")
        self.action.setWhatsThis("Configuration for My Tool")
        self.action.setStatusTip("This is status tip")
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)

        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&My Tool", self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removePluginMenu("&My Tool", self.action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def run(self):
        # not my actual file, but one which seems to reproduce the problem
        path = "/vsicurl/http://oin-hotosm.s3.amazonaws.com/59d33df023c8440011d7b26d/0/b378087a-c2a5-43a0-abec-71fcfb051150.tif"
        layer_intensity = self.iface.addRasterLayer(path, 'intensity')

        color_ramp = qgis.core.QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRamp('Viridis')
        ramp_shader = qgis.core.QgsColorRampShader(1, 255, color_ramp)

        raster_shader = qgis.core.QgsRasterShader()
        raster_shader.setRasterShaderFunction(ramp_shader)

        renderer = qgis.core.QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer_intensity.dataProvider(), 1, raster_shader)

        layer_intensity.setRenderer(renderer)
        layer_intensity.triggerRepaint()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

**metadata**

```
[general]
name=My Tool
email=dood@example.com
author=dood
qgisMinimumVersion=3.10
description=My Tool
about=Software for stuff
version=version 0.1
repository=http://www.itopen.it/repo

experimental=True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are just missing one line needed to create classifications from the color ramp:

```py
ramp_shader.classifyColorRamp()
```

So, your modified run() method would look like:

```py
def run(self):
    # not my actual file, but one which seems to reproduce the problem
    path = "/vsicurl/http://oin-hotosm.s3.amazonaws.com/59d33df023c8440011d7b26d/0/b378087a-c2a5-43a0-abec-71fcfb051150.tif"
    layer_intensity = self.iface.addRasterLayer(path, 'intensity')

    color_ramp = qgis.core.QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRamp('Viridis')
    ramp_shader = qgis.core.QgsColorRampShader(1, 255, color_ramp)
    ramp_shader.classifyColorRamp()# Add this line
    raster_shader = qgis.core.QgsRasterShader()
    raster_shader.setRasterShaderFunction(ramp_shader)

    renderer = qgis.core.QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer_intensity.dataProvider(), 1, raster_shader)

    layer_intensity.setRenderer(renderer)
    layer_intensity.triggerRepaint()
```

When I copy the logic from the method above and run directly in the QGIS Python console (after removing references to self) I get the following result:

[image]

A broader example involves retrieving the actual max and min values from the raster using the `bandStatistics()` method of `QgsRasterDataProvider` and passing them to the `QgsColorRampShader` constructor:

```py
rl = iface.activeLayer()
prov = rl.dataProvider()
stats = prov.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, rl.extent(), 0)
min = stats.minimumValue
max = stats.maximumValue
color_ramp = QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRamp('Viridis')
ramp_shader = QgsColorRampShader(min, max, color_ramp)
ramp_shader.classifyColorRamp()# Add this line
raster_shader = QgsRasterShader()
raster_shader.setRasterShaderFunction(ramp_shader)
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rl.dataProvider(), 1, raster_shader)
rl.setRenderer(renderer)
rl.triggerRepaint()
```

Results on a test DEM layer:

[image]

Comment: That indeed works and thank you for that. Any idea why it works? The docs are rather redundant; the classifyColorRamp method classifies the color ramp shader.